# Top Question Of The Week #1

Tags: discussion, qotw

QOTW has worked exceptionally well for SU (**[check out this post](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2853/57828)**)so we're stealing their format for Security.SE to add a regular feature to our **[brand new blog!](http://security.blogoverflow.com/)**

Week 1 of the "Top Question" in Security Stackexchange for the Security Stack Exchange Blog. Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why. Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake. We are looking for questions that are of great interest, or have exceptional answers. If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about, it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Note to the answerers, if you dig a question, you can always submit a draft blog post about it, even if its not picked as QotW. Check out the information at blog.superuser.com/contribute for details about how to submit blog posts. You can also visit the Blog Editors Chat Room to ask any questions you might have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QOTW blog post #1 on [How does changing your password every 90 days increase security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4704/485) will go live 15 July.