# Lists of Featured & Proposed Blog Questions

Tags: discussion, qotw, blog

I wanted to throw this up so that we have a place to list proposed [Question of the Week](http://security.blogoverflow.com/category/question-of-the-week/) [Blog posts](http://security.blogoverflow.com/), for future reference.  This question should have two CW answers:

- Questions which have been featured in the blog.

  - This includes the main QotW feature, and other questions directly linked in the blog post.
  - This should also include questions featured in other blog posts.
  - These questions should not be the main feature in future QotW posts, to favor others that have not had so much exposure.
- Questions which have been proposed as QotW, but didn't make the cut.

  - These can be used as a starting point for the QotW proposal threads.
  - We should probably start dropping questions off this list after a certain number of failed proposals.
  - Do not include already-featured questions in this list.  (i.e.: Proposals that failed one week but were picked up later, questions that got featured as part of another blog post, etc.)

Comment: It seems like it would be a good idea to have a link to the blog within this post. I don't have editing privileges yet, could someone please add the link? Here it is: http://security.blogoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3):

### Already Featured

These questions have already been linked to in existing blog posts, QotW or otherwise.  We should avoid making these a primary feature of new blog posts, unless there is a particularly special reason.  This way, we give a chance for other questions to get the same attention.  Feel free to mention these in newer posts, just not as the main focus.

- [Malicious QR Code and Mitigation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11255)
- [Why is it difficult to catch "Anonymous" or "Lulzsec" (groups)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2231/485)
- [What should I do when my boss asks me to fabricate audit log data?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11025)
- [Are powerline ethernet adapters inherently secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9725)
- [What else can be sniffed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10025)
- [Keyboards immune to signal monitoring?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2495)
- [Securing an area both physically and technically](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7065)
- [Why are hash functions one way? If I know the algorithm, why can't I calculate the input from it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11717)
- [MySQL OLD_PASSWORD cryptanalysis?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3133)
- [What's the mathematical model behind the security claims of symmetric ciphers and digest algorithms?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5101)
- [How do you destroy an old hard drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11313)
- [Best method of retiring hard drives](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6133)
- [What would one need to do in order to hijack a satellite?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6424)
- [Utility company does not hash passwords in the database](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10886)
- [When storing private identifying information in a web application, what is "industry standard" best practices?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9403)
- [What is the difference between $200 and $1,000+ Firewalls?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9409)
- [How secure are virtual machines really? False sense of security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3056)
- [Patching Mechanism and security holes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3157)
- [Certifiable standards for server security, besides PCI-DSS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6818)
- [Is this set-up PCI-Compliant?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6427)
- [Do any security experts recommend bcrypt for password storage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781)
- [XKCD #936: Short complex password, or long dictionary passphrase?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095)
- [Are there state-of-the-art techniques or theory specifically for attacking passphrases over passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6308)
- [Are there lists of most common words or ngrams used in passwords and passphrases?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6175)
- [Who is responsible for the strength of user's passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6474)
- [Should I have a maximum password length?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6287)
- [Should passwords be truly random?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6497)
- [How can I avoid my password being harvested by key loggers from internet cafes?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6272)
- [Security of passwords remembered by Windows](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6513)
- [Why do we even use passwords / passphrases next to biometrics?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6349)
- [Why do law-abiding citizens need strong security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7539)
- [Why does one need a high level of privacy/anonymity for legal activities?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7666)
- [Sony Attacks, what would you do?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4405)
- [Data categorization: Critical or not](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5245)
- [Is it possible to have a key for encryption, that cannot be used for decryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7401)
- [Asymmetric vs Symmetric Encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7219)
- [What are private key cryptography and public key cryptography, and where are they useful?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5402)
- [What's the mathematical model behind the security claims of symmetric ciphers and digest algorithms?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5101)
- [Carrying out a professional IT audit procedure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7099)
- [What is an appropriate auditing standard for a law firm?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2083)
- [How does changing your password every 90 days increase security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4704)
- [Lessons learned and misconceptions regarding encryption and cryptology](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202)
- [What to transfer? Password or its hash?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4936)
- [What are rainbow tables and how are they used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/379)
- [Can DES-based hashed password be recovered if salt is known?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5204)
- [Are passwords in memory?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3342)
- [NoScript: How to determine which sites/scripts to whitelist?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4983)
- [How feasible is it for a CA to be hacked? Which default trusted root certificates should I remove?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2268)
- [IPTables default security rules for a gateway/router?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4150)
- [Security risk of PING?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4440)
- [How to write an email regarding IT Security that will be read, and not ignored by the end user?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/5906/953)
- [What are good ways toeducate about IT security in a company?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/507)
- [What policies maximize employee buy-in to security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/666)
- [When a sysadmin leaves what extra precautions need to be taken?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/222)
- [I just discovered major security flaws in my web store?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5701)
- [What is considered the simplest (or lightest) secure development lifecycle?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/624)
- [How do you compare risks from your websites, physical perimeter, staff etc](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3584)
- [What security resources should a white-hat *developer* follow these days?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/571)
- [What are the most important security checks for new web applications?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/387)
- [What is the difference between a penetration test and a vulnerability assessment?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2837)
- [What tools are available to assess the security of a web application?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32)
- [Is there a typical step-by-step A-Z process for testing a Web site for possible exploits?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5266)
- [Books about Penetration Testing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2013)
- [Can I detect web app attacks by viewing my Apache log file?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117)
- [Is it enough to only wipe a flash drive once?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5662)
- [What are the good use cases for disk encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3214)
- [How to protect data on a thumb drive](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3067)
- [How can I reliably erase all information on a hard drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5749)
- [Does an established ssl connection mean a line is really secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5)
- [SSL TLS renegotiation vulnerability - current situation in clients](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5514)
- [What's the difference between SSL, TLS, and HTTPS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5126)
- [Forward secrecy with HTTPS and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5474)
- [Locking down web-based admin areas with personal SSL certificates](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5699)
- [Why is it difficult to catch "Anonymous" or "Lulzsec" (groups)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2231)
- [What key metrics should a CIO rely on to gauge the extent of IT risk exposure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/404)
- [How would you reason with and work with the security paranoiac on your team?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3723)
- [Can you provide loss values on security breaches?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3293)
- [What are a few good lists of threats to use to kick-off conversations with others about what worries them?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157)
- [What does defense in depth entail for a web app?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/514)
- [Best practices for securing an iPhone](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5324)
- [Hardening Linux Server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/993)
- [Best practices for securing an android device](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4391)
- [Apache Server Hardening](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77)
- [IIS and SQLServer Hardening](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2304)
- [What methods are available for securing SSH?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39)
- [How do I apply a security baseline to Windows 2008 R2?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2107)
- [Does PCI compliance really reduce risk and increase security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/622)
- [Recommended policy on password complexity](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3248)
- [Why do sites implement locking after 3 failed password attempts?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/487)
- [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211)
- [Looking for example of well-known app using unsalted hashes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2986)

Answer (score 2):

### Failed Proposals - nominated for QotW, but not selected.

- [Can we still provide confidentiality when cryptography is outlawed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3160)
- [Open Source vs Closed Source Systems](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4441)
- [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211)
- [Why do we even use passwords / passphrases next to biometrics?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6349)
- [How is "anonymous" getting ahold of all these plain-text passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6366)
- [How could one detect if Apple/Google/etc. has modified a third party application distributed through their App Stores?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9449)
- [How to defend against SSL-Exhaustion attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8456)
- [What "hacking" competitions/challenges exist?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3592)
- [What tools are available to assess the security of a web application?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32)