# Vote for your question of the week #38

Tags: discussion

For QotW #38, scheduled for publishing to the [Security Stack Exchange Blog](http://security.blogoverflow.com) on 12 October, please post as Answers, and vote for your favorite question from the whole Security Stackexchange site.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why as an answer below. Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake. We are looking for questions that are of great interest, or have exceptional answers. If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents. Also, have a look at the blog to check it hasn't already been written about.

Additionally, if you had a favourite question which didn't get selected in a previous week, repost - it may be selected this week.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be **interested in writing about it** for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about, it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

I repeat - **volunteer authors are always welcome** - we get a wider range of styles, and it puts less of a load on the regulars

Note to the answerers, if you dig a question, you can always submit a draft blog post about it, even if its not picked as QotW. Contact a moderator, or come and chat in the DMZ if you need more information.

Timings:

- Question and author selection: 1700 UTC Tuesday
- Draft submission: 0800 UTC Thursday to enable review
- Publication: 1200 UTC Friday.

**For a list of previous proposed and featured questions, look at [@Iszi's question here.](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/731/485)**

Comment: added both answers to the new post http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/1018/485

Answer (score 3):

I propose:

[Why would a virus writer bother to check to see if a machine is infected before infecting it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20951/why-would-a-virus-write-bother-to-check-to-see-if-a-machine-is-infected-before-i)

It has got quite a bit of attention. Perhaps a blog post can be written that outlines what are common or popular virus traits.

Answer (score 2):

I propose the following question

[What are the career paths in the (illegal) computer security field?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20411/what-are-the-career-paths-in-the-illegal-computer-security-field)

As the question widely covers the career paths