# how does qotw author selection process takes place?

Tags: discussion, qotw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Requests for Question of The Week blog posts](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/requests-for-question-of-the-week-blog-posts)

I recently registered for qotw author selection event in DMZ room, before participating in it, I have seen many questions on meta which state vote for your QOTW blog post which involves the process of selecting questions for blog (my guess).

I am curious to know about the process involved for selection of authors and how the entire process takes place.

Comment: Please stop using bold for random words in your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently changed how we do it - you can now vote for your QotW on a [single post](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/requests-for-question-of-the-week-blog-posts), which saves the hassle of having hundreds of QOTW questions. Anyone can submit a QotW by posting an answer. Once the selection is complete (decided by votes) someone writes a blog post on it. Usually this mainly consists of quotes from the question and answers.

We usually decide who writes the blog post in the DMZ, which is easy for a small community like ours where people aren't fighting over who gets to write what. Usually someone volunteers to do it, and they go do it. It's a quick and simple process.

Answer (score 2):

You can volunteer to write an unassigned post that was nominated at [Requests for Question of The Week blog posts](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1018/33).